# How does the onToggle prop work in this example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, components, jsx

This app has three files that transfer the same prop (`onToggle`) between eachother, but I don't understand the logic behind it. Could anyone explain to me how it works?

`App.js` Is where a prop called `onToggle` is created

```
function App(){
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Food shopping1",
      day: "Feb 5th at 2:30pm",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Food shopping2",
      day: "Feb 5th at 2:30pm",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: "Food shopping3",
      day: "Feb 5th at 2:30pm",
    },
  ]);


  //delete task
  function deleteTask(id){
    setTasks(tasks.filter(task => task["id"] !== id))
    return console.log(id)
  }

  // Toggle reminder
  function toggleReminder(id){
    console.log(id)
  }
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        {tasks.length > 0 ? <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={deleteTask} onToggle={toggleReminder}/> : "No Events"}
      </div>
    )
  }

  export default App
```

The prop is inside a component called `Tasks`

`tasks.js`

```
export const Tasks = (props) => {

  return (
  <div>
    {props.tasks.map((task) => 
        <Task key={task.id} task={task} onDelete={props.onDelete} onToggle={props.onToggle}/>
    )}
  </div>)

};
```

As you can see, the `Tasks` component consists of a `Task` prop, and it contains a `onToggle` prop

The `Task`component consists of a `react-emoji` `FaTimes` which executes `onClick` a function which returns `props.onToggle(props.task.id)`

```
export const Task = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="task">
            <h3>{props.task.text} <FaTimes style={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={() => props.onDelete(props.task.id)}
            onClick={() => props.onToggle(props.task.id)}/> </h3>
            <p>{props.task.day}</p>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Task component is basically trying to send information to the App component.

Everytime the emoji (FaTimes) is clicked in the Task component, the id of the Task component that the click action occurred in is passed to the App component. If the FaTimes icon is being used (which I assume is a delete icon), I would say, the task in question was deleted and the App component gets this update so it can react appropriately (possibly make an API call to update the state).

Step by step process:
The App component is the parent component to Tasks, which is parent to Task. The operation to react to the deletion of a task is defined in the App component. So, the Task component needs a way of communicating to the App component when a task is deleted. The method "deleteTask" is passed on to the child component Tasks as a prop and the same is passed on to the Task component as a prop. When there is a delete action in the Task component, the onClick action invokes the onDelete prop which is finally invoked in the App component to execute the deleteTask method on the Task ID that is sent as an argument to the callback function.

Comment: Could you do like a step by step explanation for each step?

Comment: I have edited the answer with an explanation.